# Can't remove .I. AND ..I. files

Tags: git

could you suggest any idea how to remove two files from filesystem:
**..I.**
and
**.I.**
?? 
While experimenting I created them with command
**$ git touch .I.**
I tried to use these commands:
**$ git rm .I.**
**$ git rm ./.I.**
**$ git rm ..I.**
**$ git rm ./..I.**
but it didn't help.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you used "git touch"?  As far as I can see, there is no such command.
To remove the files, try `rm .I.` and `rm ..I.`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I used "touch .I." command

Answer (score 0):

As described above there is not such a command `git touch` but if it can be helpful to others:

If you have special file names like with spaces on unix machine you can use the `\<space>` to remove them

```
git rm -f /file\ with \ space
```

---

Next time check the git status to get a list of all the files to see if you actually have file with this name.

Comment: Even worse than files with spaces in the name are files whose name begins with a hyphen.  One trick to get rid of them is to use `rm -i` to interactively remove certain files, in particular `rm -ri .`. This **must be used with care** to avoid removing other, wanted files!